# Using the GMail API how can I see if an account has an existing watch on it?

Tags: api, gmail, watch

I am trying to add a watch to an existing gmail account via the Gmail API but am getting the error:

Only one user push notification client allowed per developer (call /stop then try again)

How can I check to see if the gmail account already has a watch on it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Gmail API does not have a method that allows you to detect if an account already has a watch applied to it. You can always renew a watch by first stopping the watch and then immediately initiate a new watch right after.

Best practice is to store watch expiration time when you initialize a watch and always check against the stored expiration timestamp to determine if a watch needs to be renewed.